# ASP.NET MVC localization using DisplayAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I want to localize my resources (form labels, validation messages etc) using DisplayAttribute. I have my resources in the database, but looks like DisplayAttribute uses the resx files, and the class is sealed itself so I cannot derive a subclass and override the require methods/properties.

Is there any way of handling the resourcemanager used by DisplayAttribute, to get the resources from the database instead of the resx files.

And no, I can not use the resx files.

Comment: Why on earth, this is a sealed class and does not implement an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own ResourceProvider to get the messages from the database, and then set the `<globalization>` tag in Web.Config to point to your custom ResourceProvider.  .Net will then use this instead of resx files.

Detailed explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx